# Unable to call postgres & postgis function in query builder laravel 4

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4, gis

I want to use the postgis function like  `ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)`  in laravel query builder.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from basemap.saafpani_schemes";
        $mapdata = DB::connection('pspc')->select(DB::raw($sql))->get();
        return $mapdata;
```

When i tried this the following exception raised.

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function
>   st_asgeojson(public.geometry) does not exist

I tried this too:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from basemap.saafpani_schemes";
            $mapdata = DB::connection('pspc')->select($sql);
            return $mapdata;
```

Comment: Does this SQL work outside of Laravel?

Comment: Yup. its work fine in posgres query panel...

Comment: Are you using the same user to login with, when testing in the query pannel?

Comment: yup, ` SELECT * from basemap.saafpani_schemes` this query works with same login. only problem occurred when using any db function

Comment: Oh sounds like you have initialised the postgis extension. What version of postgis are you using?

Comment: Have you done `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` or run the SQL files if your using < 9.1 postgres?

Comment: thanks Mark. I found the solution.

Comment: Can you share what the solution is? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: There was error in my query. All the gis functions are defined Public schema. if you want to call from other schema you need to point public.st_function.