# PostGIS functions in Laravel queries

Tags: laravel, postgresql, postgis

I usually work with MySQL, so PostgreSQL is a new thing to me

I'm trying to use PostGIS in my queries,

```
SELECT ST_X(g.geomout), ST_Y(g.geomout) FROM geocode('?', 1) as g
```

it works as it should if I run the query in terminal, but not from Laravel

In Laravel I use `\DB::connection('pgsql')->select(...`, but it can't find the `geocode` function

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function
>   geocode(unknown, in     teger) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT ST_X(g.geomout), ST_Y(g.geomout) FROM geocode('?',
>   1)...
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: SELECT
>   ST_X(g.geomout), ST_Y(g.geomout)      FROM geocode('54 North Winter
>   Street Columbus, OH, 43015', 1) As g)
>
> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function
>   geocode(unknown, in     teger) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT ST_X(g.geomout), ST_Y(g.geomout) FROM geocode('?',
>   1)...
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument
>   types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

but this query works fine in terminal

```
SELECT ST_X(g.geomout), ST_Y(g.geomout)
FROM geocode('54 North Winter Street Columbus, OH, 43015', 1) As g
```

PostGIS extension is enabled, if I run:

```
\DB::connection('pgsql')->select("SELECT postgis_full_version()")
```

I'll get the result with the version info

`search_path` is set to `"$user", public, postgis`, originally it was `"$user", public`, nothing changed

I also tried to use `public.geocode` ([Unable to call postgres & postgis function in query builder laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35180555/846437)), same result

**UPDATE:**

I have `tiger_geocoder` extension, `geocode` is defined there, I need to use `tiger.geocode`, but then `ST_X/ST_Y` will fail, because they are defined in `public`

The final query looks like `SELECT public.ST_X(g.geomout), public.ST_Y(g.geomout) FROM tiger.geocode(?, 1) As g`

but now I get:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function
>   soundex(unknown) does not exist

how can I define all these functions on a single schema?

**UPDATE 2:**

That's the problem, `search_path` for the connection in Laravel doesn't have all that info, it set to `public`, even though I have path with all schemas if I access postgresql `search_path` is set to `"$user", public, tiger, postgis`. How do I make this global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for Laravel in `database.php` need to add `schema` as array, e.g. `'schema' => ['$user', 'public','postgis','tiger'],`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `tiger` to your search path. There is no need to qualify every function, they can be located in different schemas... as long as these schemas are in the search path!

Comment: ok, that's the problem, `search_path` for the connection in Laravel doesn't have all that info, it set to `public`, even though I have path with all schemas if I access postgresql `search_path` is set to `"$user", public, tiger, postgis`. How do I make this global?